# Excel - Apply formula according to dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So in this excel, we focus only on the A and S column. I already did some manually to show you what the desired result looks like.

[image]

For example, A4 (2-Jan-21), in S4 column, it's 20800, which is the formula =V3xW3 (4160x5). Then in A5 which contains the duplicate 2-Jan-21, I want S5 to be the same number as the above row, which is 20800, or =S4.

This applies to all the dates you can see here. So for A6 or 3-Jan-21, S6 becomes =V5xW5. A7 or 5-Jan-21, S7 becomes =V6xW6. Duplicates of 5-Jan-21 copies the row above so S8 = S7, S9 = S8, S10 = S9 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried someting, please share it with us, as it is much easier to solve a problem on something that already exists than to code it from scratch. This way it is much more likely that you get an answer that really helps you.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It would help if you can add some context. What does the number in column V signify? Why is it multiplied by 5? What are you trying to do here? It looks like V might be the number in the row above plus the number in T. I think it's probably easily solved, but context will help us get the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting correctly this is very straightforward.  I believe the logic you are seeking is:

If this is the first instance of a date, then S should equal (v * w).  If this is not the first instance of that date, this row's S should equal the S value from the first instance of this date.  Expressed as a pseudocoded If-Then it would be:

```
IF (this row's date = previous row's date) THEN
    This row's S = previous row's S
ELSE
    This row's S = this row's V times this row's W
```

Or using excel references, row 2 logic would be:

```
IF (A2 = A1) THEN
    S2 = S1
ELSE
    S2 = V2 * W2
```

Once we've expressed the logic this clearly, the Excel way of expressing this logic is to place in cell S2 this formula:

```
=IF(A2=A1,S1,V2*W2)
```

And then this formula is just copied down.

I'm hoping this helps you form a way of expressing the logic and only then creating the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much again Max. The formula worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

As `Max` says.

If you have `Spill` functionality and want to write a single formula, you might use:

```
=IF(A2:A6 = A1:A5,  V1:V5 * W1:W5,  V2:V6 * W2:W6)
```

While it seems preferable to use `S1:S5` for the TRUE result, that will lead to circularity in a `Spill` formula written so. But just placing the calculation that would be in the "above" cell will work fine in that regard.

But... not in every regard. While it works nicely for the second instance of a date in column A, it does NOT work for a third. But a lookup that matches the date for that row in Column A to the first instance of the date in the whole of column A and returns the calculation for that row would work:

```
=IF(A2:A6=A1:A5,  INDEX(V2:V6*W2:W6,  MATCH(A2:A6,A2:A6,0),  ),  V2:V6*W2:W6)
```

That gives `Spill` results, so one formula fills all the needed cells rather than having to continue to paste the formula down as more rows of data are added.

(However, it while it will work if out-of-order dates should be treated similarly, it will not work if a date that matches one above it in column A, but not immediately above it (so the date in row 100 matches that in row 32, but row 99 has some other date altogether), is to be treated differently, as a new occurrence altogether.)

(By the way, notice the `INDEX` in the formula works even though it is not given any kind of "physical" range. That's because it works on an array built in the formula for the calculation. While nice, sometimes that is a problem as some functions have the arrays they produce limited in length. Not `INDEX` so no worries, but some do and your formulas could give very wrong results rather than fail in some obvious way (though they may do that, for sure!). Even if `INDEX` had been given a range, the formula would still form the array and then use it rather than use the actual cells in the range. Makes me wonder sometimes if you gave `INDEX` an array of results that was longer than the 1,048,576 count of cells in a column if it would accept it, fail outright, or just use the first 1,048,576 values. Seems like it should succeed, and so one could create and use a virtual range much larger than the spreadsheet itself offers... hmm...)